# Are there any general existence results for Leray coverings?

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

When doing concrete calculations of the sheaf cohomology groups $H^k(X;\mathcal F)$ for some topological space $X$ and some sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$, it is usually easiest to make use of Leray coverings. However, sometimes one can prove a statement of the form "for any open covering $U$ of $X$, $H^k(U;\mathcal F)$ equals [something]". Then, if one knows there *exists* a Leray covering, this suffices to determine $H^k(X;\mathcal F)$. This leads me to ask the following question:

> Are there any concrete criteria to determine whether a sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$ admits a Leray covering?

In particular, is there *always* a Leray covering? I am particularly interested in the case where $X$ is a complex manifold, or even a Riemann surface; I don't know if this makes things easier.

Comment: I know two main cases. If you consider coherent sheaves, then yes Leray cover exists on every complex manifold. If you consider (locally) constant sheaves, again Leray coverings always exist on every topological manifold.

Comment: @Roland I'd be interested in an exposition! :-)

Comment: @Roland would you be interested in either writing an answer or at least providing a source?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have any sources. This is the kind of result I know thought I never read a proof, nor I am interested in seeing one ;) I am assuming these are really technical and not particularly enlightening. The only case I did read a proof was in the context of schemes.